# Salesforce System.AsyncException - scheduled class calls Queueable apex do a callout and then calls batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, callout, queueable

I have a schedule apex class that calls Queueable apex which calls a class that do a callout and then execute batch.

I receive System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.

```
global class WorkdayGetRequisitionsSch Implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts{ 
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        System.enqueueJob(new WorkdayGetRequisitionsQueueable());
    }
}

public with sharing class WorkdayGetRequisitionsQueueable implements Queueable , Database.AllowsCallouts { 
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Workday.getRequisitions();
    }
}

getRequisitions(){
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
...
Database.executeBatch(new  WorkdayGetRequisitionsBatchJobs(mapStaffingJobs.Values()), 10 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
Remove the Database.AllowsCallouts from the schedule class because salesforce will assume a future method is calling another future method although the schedule class is not doing a callout